Запуск .jar без скачивания
Здрвствуйте
Пишу программу на питоне, нужен способ запускать .jar файл не храня его на компьютере, запускать например из сервера где он хранится. Есть ли такая возможность?

Используйте Paramiko. ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute)

URLClassLoader, JarURLConnection.

@void, мне надо запустить .jar на компьютере с которого выполняется программа, а не на сервере

Вашему компьютеру должно присниться, что внутри jar? У вас много программ на компьютере, которые вы запускаете, но они установлены у вашего соседа?
